# Azure Cosmos DB upload JSON file via C#/.net

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am looking for a way to upload a JSON file directly to my Azure Cosmos DB container.
I am aware of the "classic" way doing it like:

- load the JSON file
- convert it via `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(data)`;
- upload it like "`container.CreateItemAsync(item)`"

I would like to skip the part where I have to deserialize the JSON and convert it into a C# object.

Is there a method or way like this?

```
container.CreateItemAsync(myData.json)
```

Comment: It should be possible but depends on the SDK version are you using. Tell use the name of the nuget package you installed into your project, please.

Comment: I.e. is it `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` (old) or `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` (new)?

Comment: How about `container.CreateItemStreamAsync()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.createitemstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Have you tried `CreateItemAsync<JObject>()`. I don't think you can pass the JSON string directly, but a parsed JSON should work.

Answer (score 2):

With the Cosmos DB SQL API v3 .NET SDK, there is a stream option which will allow already serialized payloads to be passed in `container.CreateItemStreamAsync()`